# How can you update gitlab users after changing LDAP OU

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ce

I'm currently playing around with `gitlab-ce` (omnibus, on an Ubuntu VM) in an environment with LDAP authentication.
The LDAP administrator recently reconfigured the `OU`s from something like

`ou=temp, ou=users, ou=baseinfrastructure` to
`ou=users, ou=baseinfrastructure`.

Now when I do something as simple as `git pull` with a regular user account, that user account will be set to `ldap_blocked` since gitlab queries for the user with the `temp` part in the `cn` string and obviously doesn't find it.

Is there a way to update the users or something else so gitlab no longer queries with the `ou=temp,`  part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some search, I've found out the information is stored in the `identities` table.

In gitlab omnibus, you can start a database console using `gitlab-psql`.

In my case, the required query for verifying I'm doing the right thing was:

```
SELECT external_uid, replace(external_uid, 'ou=temp,', '') FROM identities;
```

and then actually replacing them by executing:

```
UPDATE identities SET external_uid = replace(external_uid, 'ou=temp,', '');
```

Answer (score 2):

For a single user you can use `gitlab-rails console`.

Find your user:

```
user = User.find_by_email("user@email")
```

Get user `extern_uid`:

```
user.ldap_identity.extern_uid
```

the above should print result similar to: `=> "uid=username,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com"`

Update values as neccesary:

```
user.ldap_identity.extern_uid = "uid=newusername,ou=newpeople,dc=example,dc=com"
```

Verify:

```
user.ldap_identity.extern_uid
=> "uid=newusername,ou=newpeople,dc=example,dc=com"
```

And finally save

```
user.save
```

I believe this script [Gitlab rake task to mass update ldap dn](https://github.com/derJD/gitlab_update_ldap_dn)  may be useful for updating multiple users at once.